# Transform Triangle Mesh OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, transform, mesh

I am trying to transform a picture with OpenCV in python.

Therefore I have points in a grid placed on the image that I can also move.
I then split each grid rectangle into two triangles and I have their coordinates:

- where they were at the beginning and
- where they are after i moved some points around
  Now I want to transform the image so it fits the new mesh but without seeing lines on the edges of the triangles or image pieces getting ripped by transforming differently.

Help!

Comment: Use barycentric interpolation. See https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/barycentric-coordinates and https://cgg.mff.cuni.cz/~pepca/lectures/cv/080warptriangles.en.php and https://wujiadi.wordpress.com/2019/06/02/mesh-based-image-warping/

Comment: i ended up using skimage transform.warp, but thank you still. was a really interesting insight, but runtime wise terrible, at least my own implementation